# How to fade in an input field type text at the place of dropdown when one value is selected in Bootstrap drop-down in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am having an bootstrap drop down in AngularJS, I am able to select the value and show the selected value in the drop down, ex:

```
<div> ng-repeat="l in languages">
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-hide="!$index!=0">
    <span class="input-group-btn btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="btnLanguageDDL">{{l.Language}} <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" id="Ul3">
                <li ng-click="languageSelClick('French',$index)">
                    <input  id="Radio15" name="weight_unit" type="radio" value="kg" /> <label for="language-french">French </label>
                </li>
                .....similar
                <li ng-click="languageSelClick('Other',$index)">
                    <input  id="Radio22" name="weight_unit" type="radio" value="kg" /> <label for="language-other">Other </label>
                 </li>
            </ul>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is once the Other is selected then I want to fade-out select drop down box and fade-in empty input field.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option could be to bind an `ng-model` to your dropdown.

You can then put an `ng-show` on your empty `input` field which will can watch for the value of your dropdown to be `Other`.

You probably don't actually want to hide the dropdown itself?

Comment: I wan't to hide the drop-down and show the input field.

Comment: Ok, seems like a bad user experience, but put an `ng-hide` on your dropdown to watch for the `ng-model` value.

Comment: That won't work Bro reason,  if you have given ng-model and write ng-show and hide for ex on drop-down we would write ng-hide="l.Language=='Other'" and on the input if you write as ng-show="l.Language=='Other'" then once you select the drop-down value to other then drop-down would disappear and input would appear, once  you start changing the text in the input box from other to any thing else then again drop-down woud appear, after hiding the drop-down i want to enter the value in the input box.